# When is InvocationTargetException.getCause() null?

Tags: java, invocationtargetexception

As per the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationTargetException.html#getCause%28%29), `InvocationTargetException.getCause()` can be null:

> Returns the cause of this exception (the thrown target exception, which may be null).

But the documentation also says that it wraps an existing exception:

> InvocationTargetException is a checked exception that wraps an exception thrown by an invoked method or constructor.

So it seems to me that `InvocationTargetException.getCause()` **can never be `null`.**

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE**

Yes, I missed something -- the default constructor of `InvocationTargetException` would cause `getCause()` to be null.

The question I have now is why provide a default constructor for this class at all. Is there a usecase where the exception needs to be thrown with a null cause?

Comment: You could just `throw new InvocationTargetException()`, which is a protected constructor.

Comment: Missed the default constructor that would cause this, but now I can't understand what it needs a default constructor

Comment: Future-proofing maybe. Why language designers do things is hard to answer.

Answer (score 2):

So.

@xtravar's comment on [my (much) earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17685821/978502) has caused be to have another look at this issue. And I might just got it. Please bear with me.

`InvocationTargetException` was introduced to Java very early. At least as early as some JDK 1.1.X which dates back to anywhere [between February 1997 to December 1998](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29#Versions). How do I know it's that old? After all, there's no `@since 1.1` mark on the class.
I happened to see the following javadoc on the `serialVersionUID` field:

```
/**
 * Use serialVersionUID from JDK 1.1.X for interoperability
 */
```

Right. So what?
So, according to docs of `Throwable.getCause()`, which `InvocationTargetException` eventually inherits:

```
While it is typically unnecessary to override this method, a subclass can
override it to return a cause set by some other means. This is appropriate
for a "legacy chained throwable" that predates the addition of chained
exceptions to Throwable.
...
@since 1.4
```

Now, please combine this with the following note on `InvocationTargetException` class docs:

```
As of release 1.4, this exception has been retrofitted to conform to
the general purpose exception-chaining mechanism.  The "target exception"
that is provided at construction time and accessed via the
getTargetException() method is now known as the cause,
and may be accessed via the Throwable.getCause() method,
as well as the aforementioned "legacy method."
```

See where I'm getting at?
The note on `Throwable.getCause()` is aimed exactly at `InvocationTargetException` (for the least). `InvocationTargetExcpetion` was used to chain exceptions *before* exception-chaining was introduced to `Throwable`...

And when `InvocationTargetException` was retrofitted, as noted, I assume that the language designers wanted to:

1. prevent the possibility of `InvocationTargetException` having two different "causes" - one stored in `target` and the other in `cause`; and still
2. be backward-compatible with existing code that relies on the `target` field.

That's why they left the `target` field as the one that's really used and implemented any existing constructors so that the `cause` field remains `null` for good. The implementation of `getCause()` for `InvocationTargetException`, of course, returns `target` as the cause.

So to answer

> Is there a usecase where the exception needs to be thrown with a null cause?

Not really, it's not how the class is - and was - *intended* to be used.

And yet, this question remains:

> why provide a default constructor for this class at all

(and [this constructor seems to exist ever since](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall97/cs461/jdkdocs/api/java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.html#InvocationTargetException()))

I tend to think that this class is actually quite `null`-tolerant. After all, the `public` constructors **permit `null` as the `Throwable target`**. As a designer, if you already permitted that, you may as well add the `protected` default constructor that explicitly assigns `null` to `target`, enabling inheriting classes to construct the class however needed.

This also answers the original question:

> So it seems to me that InvocationTargetException.getCause() can never
>   be null.
>
> Am I missing something?

Yes. `InvocationTargetException` is indeed *intended* to have a non-`null` `target` and `cause`. However, what's "missed" here is that `target` (and hence `cause`) unfortunately *can* be `null`, as nothing in the class forces it otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for very detailed analysis! I do believe you are pretty much on the mark, and the last paragraph summarizes quite nicely.

Answer (score 1):

`InvocationTargetException` extends `ReflectiveOperationException` which states

> Common superclass of exceptions thrown by reflective operations in
>   core reflection.

When you use reflection to call a method (or constructor).

```
Method method = ...
method.invoke(instance, ...);
```

If the method threw an exception, it would be stored in the `target` field of `InvocationTargetException`. That'll happen in most reflection cases.

The fact that there is an empty constructor leads me to believe it might be used differently in other cases.

**JDK 7**

```
private Throwable target;

/**
 * Constructs an {@code InvocationTargetException} with
 * {@code null} as the target exception.
 */
protected InvocationTargetException() {
    super((Throwable)null);  // Disallow initCause
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you -- I don't see how InvocationTargetException can ever be null, because it's only thrown when the target throws an exception.

My guess is that the text for getCause() that states "which may be null" is just boilerplate copied from the Throwable.getCause() Javadoc.

Comment: As others have pointed out there is at least a syntactic possibility that getCause may be null, but I don't see a point of allowing it

Answer (score 0):

First, its worth mentioning that not only `null` cause is permitted via the `protected` constructor. You can also invoke the `public` construcors with `target` valued to `null`. No `NullPointerException` will occur...

Having said that, it *does* seem like more than something that the designers just slipped.

Could be that the designers wanted to enable instantiating the class via reflection, as in:

```
Constructor ctor = // ... some code to get the no-arg constructor that I spared here
ctor.setAccessible(true); // it's protected constructor...
InvocationTargetException e = (InvocationTargetException) ctor.newInstance();
```

That way, util method can create `InvocationTargetException` instances and pass them to client code that adds up the particular cause.

Comment: That seems to be the only plausible reason, but it is still not clear what usecase would require using reflection to construct an instance used default no-param ctor

Comment: @MiserableVariable [Hibernate 3.5 used to do that](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/persistent-classes.html#persistent-classes-pojo-constructor) ;) (and [in some places it still does...](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html_single/#d5e590)), though not for `InvocationTargetException`.

Comment: Creating objects, even exceptions, by reflection is perhaps not unusual. But none of this answers my question, IMHO, which is admittedly somewhat subjective.

Comment: The null cause is permitted publicly now.  So, that's awkward.
http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationTargetException.java.html