# Is there any scenario where InvocationTargetException getCause() return null ?When JVM create it s Object

Tags: java

Is there any scenario where InvocationTargetException getCause()method return null?provided we are not creating InvocationTargetException explicitly using no arg constructor.

In short is JVM create InvocationTargetException with no arg constructor??

Comment: Just curious what difference it makes. If it's possible to be `null`, Murphy's Law says your assumption that, in practice, it never is, will be violated. Probably at the worst possible time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is InvocationTargetException.getCause() null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684484/when-is-invocationtargetexception-getcause-null)